# Is there a single, opposite word to “alibi”?

Tags: single-word-requests

Oxford Advanced Learner’s Dictionary defines “alibi” as 1. evidence that proves that a person was in another place at the time of a crime and so could not have committed it. 2. an excuse for sth that you have done wrong.

Is there an opposite, single word (not like ‘evidence of presence’) to “alibi” denoting evidence that "positively" proves that a person was in the place at the time of an event taking place regardress whether it's associated with or not? For instance, I want to prove that I was "there" at a dinner party last night, not at another or other places, or I want to show off a picture taken at a dinner show together with movie stars.

If there is no opposite word, or antonym to "alibi," it's fine.

P.S. I checked the list of past ‘Is there single word for xxx” questions. I didn’t find the same question. However if there is, I’m willing to delete this question.

Comment: Why do you think a word like that would have an opposite? Generally only adjectives have opposites.

Comment: Are you looking for something like red-handedness? http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/red-handedness

Comment: @Skimninge. No. I’m looking for a convenient single word to prove my presence at the place in question, but not necessarily limited to crime scene. For instance. I was at a dinner party. I need the evidence to prove that I was there to my wife, contrary to alibi.

Comment: @curiousdanni. Antonym isn't all adjectives.

Comment: @YoichiOishi - if the term you are looking for is not necessarily related to a crime scene, I think you should add that piece of information in your question!!

Comment: @YoichiOishi Oh, so you want a *doctor's note* or your *parking validated*? ;)

Comment: Wouldn't alibi work both ways? Either to confirm that you were or were not at the dinner party?

Comment: @YoichiOishi - if you can prove your attendance  at a dinner party to your wife, that *is* your alabi: *an excuse usually intended to avert blame or punishment (as for failure or negligence.)*

Comment: The commonness of the expression "We can tie (or something or someone ties) him (or her) to the scene of the crime" suggests to me that there is probably no one-word equivalent.

Comment: If an alibi is *evidence that a person was not at the location of a crime when it was committed,* then the opposite of an alibi would be evidence that a person was at the location of a crime when it was committed. Are you asking if there is a single word which carries that meaning? The more I read your second paragraph, the less I understand what you're trying to ask: " proves that a person was in the place at the time of an event taking place regardless whether it's associated with or not?" 1. By event, do you mean crime? 2. regardless whether *what* is associated with *what*?

Comment: "... prove that I was "there" at a dinner party last night, ..., or I want to show off a picture taken at a dinner show together with movie stars. 3. Was the dinner party the location where a crime was committed? Why are you talking about a dinner party as an example? It's an example of what?

Comment: ＠JIｍRaynpolds. We have both “存在証明- Sonzai-shomei” meaning the proof of your being there” and ”不在証明-Fuzai-shomei ” meaning the proof of your not being there in Japanese, the latter of which I think corresponds to alibi, though both “Sonzai-shomei” and “Fuzai-shomei” aren’t necessarily associated with a crime scene, and can be applied to the innocuous scenes like dinner party. The difference of “存在証明” and “不在証明” is just the first one character, but the meaning is opposite. I’m curious to know if there is the English counterpart to “存在証明 - Sonzai-shomei.” in single or two words like "alibi".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**[proof](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk%3AProof_%28truth%29#2012-8-7_-_semiprotected)**
*evidence or argument establishing or helping to establish a fact or the truth of a statement.*

> Here's the proof (you've been asking for) that I was at a dinner party last night.

This answers the OP example: *For instance, I want to prove that I was "there" at a dinner party last night, not at another or other places, or I want to show off a picture taken at a dinner show together with movie stars..*

While I agree with Josh61 that *proof* is not the antonym for *alibi*, you wouldn't say about a photo which testifies your presence at a dinner party as: "This is my alibi..."

Comment: Proof/evidence are not univocal..that may prove or disprove something, like alibi. The are more synonyms than antonyms  IMO.

Comment: It is a tricky issue!!!

Comment: Alibi has a ' you have something to hide' connotation that is not present in your example, either as a synonym or antonym. That why you wouldn'd say ' this photo is my alibi'.

Comment: +1 Jokingly, you could refer to the image that establishes a time or place as *proof of life*, darkly akin to a kidnapped victim's picture with a dated newspaper.

Comment: It's a related word, but not an antonym.

Comment: @JimReynolds I know that, I even said so in the answer but *proof* fits the OP's request. You wouldn't say to someone "Do want the smoking gun that I danced with Anne Hathaway last night?" You'd say: *proof* or *evidence*. Give me the word that fits the OP's example from the answers that have been posted so far.

Comment: OK. I see after reading more carefully, that you did say that. My mistake! I also see, after reading again and more carefully, that the OP's question is, in my opinion, confused! He first gives quite a simple definition, and he asks for an antonym, but the language in the second paragraph is actually confused and unclear.

Answer (score 6):

If an alibi is "exculpatory evidence", the its opposite would be "damning evidence"; the English idiom which more concisely communicates the idea of damning evidence is ***smoking gun***.

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoking_gun), for example:

> The term "**smoking gun**" was originally, and is still primarily, a reference to **an object or fact that serves as conclusive evidence of a crime** or similar act. In addition to this, its meaning has evolved in uses completely unrelated to criminal activity: for example, scientific evidence that is highly suggestive in favor of a particular hypothesis is sometimes called smoking gun evidence. **Its name originally came from the idea of finding a smoking (i.e., very recently fired) gun on the person** of a suspect wanted for shooting someone, which in that situation would be **nearly unshakable proof of having committed the crime**. A piece of **evidence that falls just short of being conclusive is sometimes referred to as a "smoldering gun."**

So the power of idiom is derived from its clear imagery.

Comment: But an alibi is a specific type of exculpatory evidence, relating to establishment of location and period. A smoking gun is one type of *incriminating* evidence, but so is, say, a fingerprint. Is fingerprint another antonym for alibi? No, so being incriminating evidence doesn't = being an opposite of *alibi.*

Comment: An alibi is definitive (of innocence). A 'smoking gun' is convincing but still questionable (but this may still be the best alternative).

Comment: @Mitch Read the first and last bolded passages from the Wikipedia article.

Answer (score 3):

The opposite of ***alibi***, if there is one, surely is ***in flagrante delicto***, meaning *in the very act of wrongdoing (especially in an act of sexual misconduct)*.
There are difficulties with this since, as you observe, *alibi* is a noun and this expression is adverbial.

But it would appear to me that proof of your attendance at the dinner party (as someone observed) constitutes an *alibi*. The worst-case opposite of that would have been to have been caught ***in flagrante delicto***.

Comment: But one can be proven to have been somewhere at an opportune time without being *in flagrante delicato,* delicious a term as it is.

Answer (score 1):

Well, an alibi is said to be "exculpatory" (taking away blame), so if "culpatory" is a word, it would mean  "attaching blame to".

Other adjectives include "damning" or "incriminating" (evidence), which helps to establish "culpability".

If the perpetrator was caught in the act, he is said to have been "caught red-handed".  The cops could be said to "have the goods on him". If the evidence is strong, prosecuting attorney  has an "ironclad case" or an "open-and-shut case" against him.  The evidence might be said to be "incontrovertible" (cannot be disproved).

A related term is "corpus delicti", which refers to proving that a crime has been committed (you can't be proven guilty of a crime unless prosecutors can establish that a crime has been committed.)

But none of these is an actual one-word noun opposite of "alibi".

Answer (score 1):

What you are seeking is a single-word noun that means "proof or evidence of presence".

I'm pretty sure that no such word exists in English.

However, given that *alibi* is a Latin word, perhaps we can at least invent a corresponding Latin expression that means "indication of presence".

Accordingly, I propose the term ***indicium praesentiae.*** Admittedly, this isn't the type of expression most people would want to drop into a casual conversation, but I can see it having its uses in the courtroom, medicine or other specialized contexts.

Answer (score -1):

When you've been somewhere, you will have left a ***trace*** there. Unlike ***alibi***, this is not something that you've actually *got*, but it is something that you inevitably *leave* wherever you go.

From Merriam-Webster:

> trace *(n.)*
>   2.
>   *a* :  a mark or line left by something that has passed;  also : *footprint*
>   *b* :  a path, trail, or road made by the passage of animals, people, or vehicles
>   3.
>   *a* :  a sign or evidence of some past thing :  ***vestige***
>   6.
>   *a* :  a minute and often barely detectable amount or indication : a trace of a smile

This word applies at every level, from [forensic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_evidence) (detectable physical marks of your presence) to psychological (people will have noticed and remembered you).

Answer (score -1):

Well, sir, I am afraid I could not find a single word.

However if you want to emphasize that you really were there, " for instance, I want to prove that I was "there" at a dinner party last night, not at another or other places, or I want to show off a picture taken at a dinnaer show together with movie stars" as you said, **being there** is not enough.

So let me suggest Julius Caesar's famous quote: [Veni, Vidi, Vici](http://ancienthistory.about.com/od/vterms/g/Venividivici.htm) which means '**I came, I saw, I conquered** (http://ancienthistory.about.com/).